# What would you call it if you want to convert the simple binding of a book to the form shown in the picture?

Tags: word-request

What would you call it if you want to convert the simple binding of a book to the form is shown in the picture?

[image]

What is verb of doing this? And what is the name of these rings?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These kinds of notebooks are called "spiral-bound" notebooks. Here, spiral-bound is an adjective describing the notebook. We can use the word "spiral-bind" as a verb. We could say:

I would like to spiral-bind this book/notebook.

Here is a wiki page teaching about the making of spiral-bound books:

https://www.wikihow.com/Make-a-Spiral%E2%80%90Bound-Book

Answer (score 5):

Removing the binding from a book and replacing it is referred to as "re-binding"

The binding shown in the picture appears is a "spiral binding"

So you could talk of "re-binding the book with a spiral binding".

If the book was not previously bound you would just talk about "spiral binding the book".